# Concurrent Conflicts

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to find consecutive datetimes in Python. I got to the point where I'm able to find if each row conflicts through a loop but am stuck on how to find out if an Event was concurrent. Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this? Open to a similar approach as well!

***Concurrent means when Name and Event Date is the same and the count of consecutive conflicts >= 3.***

**Sample Data 1:**

| Event ID | Name | Date | Event Start | Event End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Hoper, Charles | 8/4/20 | 8/4/20 8:30 AM | 8/4/20 10:30 AM |
| 456 | Hoper, Charles | 8/4/20 | 8/4/20 8:50 AM | 8/4/20 9:20 AM |
| 789 | Hoper, Charles | 8/4/20 | 8/4/20 8:30 AM | 8/4/20 10 AM |
| 1011 | Perez, Daniel | 8/10/20 | 8/10/20 9 AM | 8/10/20 11 AM |
| 1213 | Shah, Kim | 8/5/20 | 8/5/20 12 PM | 8/5/20 1 PM |
| 1415 | Shah, Kim | 8/5/20 | 8/5/20 12:30 PM | 8/5/20 1 PM |

**Current Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel(r'[Path]\TestConcurrent.xlsx')

df['Start'] = df['Event Start']
df['End'] = df['Event End']



df['conflict'] = len(df) 

 #Edit from answer
    df['concurrent']  = df.groupby(['Name','Event Date','conflict'])['Event ID'].transform('count').ge(3)
    
    print(df)
```

**Current Output:**

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**Expected Output:**

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, final approach! If I understand then you don't care about the "Consecutive" column, you just want to know about the 3 overlapping windows in a row. Here's an approach that tries to answer that question immediately. It passes the two test datasets (thanks for editing!)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
import io

#Creating the test df you provided
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Event ID;Name;Date;Event Start;Event End
123;Hoper, Charles;8/4/20;8/4/20 8:30 AM;8/4/20 10:30 AM
456;Hoper, Charles;8/4/20;8/4/20 8:50 AM;8/4/20 9:20 AM
789;Hoper, Charles;8/4/20;8/4/20 8:30 AM;8/4/20 10 AM
1011;Perez, Daniel;8/10/20;8/10/20 9 AM;8/10/20 11 AM
1213;Shah, Kim;8/5/20;8/5/20 12 PM;8/5/20 1 PM
1415;Shah, Kim;8/5/20;8/5/20 12:30 PM;8/5/20 1 PM
"""),sep=';')

#Overridding with The second test df
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Event ID;Name;Date;Event Start;Event End
88;Cooper, Herbert;10/20/20;10/20/20 8:10 AM;10/20/20 9:48 AM
99;Cooper, Herbert;10/20/20;10/20/20 9:19 AM;10/20/20 11:30 AM
10;Cooper, Herbert;10/20/20;10/20/20 11:52 AM;10/20/20 1:26 PM
11;Cooper, Herbert;10/20/20;10/20/20 1:22 AM;10/20/20 2:15 PM
12;Cooper, Herbert;10/20/20;10/20/20 3:23 PM;10/20/20 4:10 PM
"""),sep=';')

df['Event Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Event Start'])
df['Event End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Event End'])
df['overlap'] = False

#Iterating line by line keeping track of whether 3 conflicts are found
last_name = None
last_date = None
last_end = pd.Timestamp.max
num_consecutive = 0

for i,r in df.iterrows():
    
    streak_continues = all([
        last_name == r['Name'],
        last_date == r['Date'],
        r['Event Start'] < last_end,
    ])
        
    if not streak_continues:
        if num_consecutive >= 3:
            df.loc[
                df['Name'].eq(last_name) & df['Date'].eq(last_date),
                'overlap'
            ] = True
            
        num_consecutive = 0
        
    last_name = r['Name']
    last_date = r['Date']
    last_end = r['Event End']
    num_consecutive += 1
        
df
```

Comment: This seems to be grouping by Name and Date and counting Event ID and doesn't look at if its a conflict. If you change the start and end date for Event ID 789 to fall outside the overlapping times, it still results as TRUE. Overlapped column determines if Event Start/End date overlap with any other rows if Name == Name. Example, Event 123 and 456 overlap because 456 starts before 123 ends. Concurrent is consecutive conflicts if count >= 3

Comment: Thanks this is super helpful, could you add that description to the question above? I'll take a poke at this again since you're right that the current answer does not work

Comment: Sure will do. Also, I tried this: df['concurrent']  = df.groupby(['Name','Event Date','conflict'])['Event ID'].transform('count').ge(3) from your approach. Although its coming up as correct, it doesn't result TRUE for other scenarios which I will post as well.

Comment: Can you try the updated solution?

Comment: I tested your new approach on Sample Data 2 with no luck. This time it seems to be counting all occurrences where Name and Event Date are the same. So concurrent column for all 5 rows is coming up as TRUE when they should all be FALSE since none of them are consecutive conflicts

Comment: Ok let me try this out. Actually, I do care about the conflicts and the consecutive columns and would need both in there. I'll add df['overlap'] = False to make sure it includes it

Comment: Works great, appreciate your help!!